# Unconditional Basis definition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

A basis $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of a Banach space $X$ is unconditional
if for each $x \in X$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n^*(x)u_n$
converges unconditionally.
It is easily verified that $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is an unconditional basis of $X$ if
and only if $(u_{\pi(n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ is a basis of $X$ for every
permutation $\pi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}.$

***Q1 How to prove that a basis is unconditional if and only if there is a
constant $C$ such that $\|P_{A^c}\| \leq C$ for every finite set $A
\subset \mathbb{N}.$ This is problem no. 10.15 p.293 from book "Topics in Banach space theory by Fernando and Nigel j. Kalton"***

From book "introduction to Banach spaces and their geometry by Bernard Beauzamy" For a Schauder basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}},$ the following properties
are equivalent:

a ) $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an unconditional basis.

b ) For every convergent series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n e_n,$ and every sequence $(\epsilon_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\epsilon_n = \pm{1} \forall n \in \mathbb{N},$ the series $\displaystyle \sum_n \epsilon_n a_n e_n$ converges.

c)  For every convergent series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n e_n,$ and every strictly increasing sequence $(n_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of integers, the series $\sum_i a_{n_i} e_{n_i}$ converges.

d)  For every convergent series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n e_n,$ and every sequence of scalars $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that, for all $n, |b_n| \leq |a_n|,$ the series $\displaystyle \sum_n b_n e_n$ converges.

e) For every $\epsilon >0,$ every convergent series $\displaystyle \sum_n a_n e_n = x,$ there is a finite subset $A_0$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that, for every finite $A \supset A_0, \|\sum_{i \in A} a_i e_i - x\| < \epsilon.$

f) There exists a constant $K \geq 1$ such that if $A$ and $B$ are finite subsets of $\mathbb{N},$ with $A \subset B,$ then for any sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of scalars :
$\|\sum_{n \in A} a_n e_n\| \leq K \|\sum_{n \in B} a_n e_n\|.$

***Q2 Does any of these items give this meaning that "a basis is unconditional if and only if there is a
constant $C$ such that $\|P_{A^c}\| \leq C$ for every finite set $A
\subset \mathbb{N}.$ Moreover, $K_{su} = \sup_{|A|<\infty}
\|P_{A^c}\|.$"***

Also, from book "Topics in Banach space theory by Fernando and Nigel j. Kalton" A basis $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of a Banach space $X$ is unconditional
if and only if there is a constant $K \geq 1$ such that for all $N
\in \mathbb{N},$
\begin{eqnarray}
\| \sum_{n=1}^N a_n u_n\| \leq K \| \sum_{n=1}^N
b_n u_n\|,
\end{eqnarray}
whenever $a_1,...,a_N,b_1,...,b_N$ are scalars
satisfying $|a_n|\leq|b_n|$ for $n=1,...,N.$

***Q3 What this mean?***

Comment: I think that Q2 is solved in Prop 3.1.5 in the same book